# store procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tired from :

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tlu30khtd_findkhs //
create procedure tlu30khtd_findkhs(in kehoachso varchar(15)) 
begin
    select *from TLU30KeHoachTuyenDung where KeHoachSo = kehoachso;
end; //
delimiter;
```

and when I call procedure with:

```
call tlu30khtd_findkhs('KH0001')
```

but result don't use

```
where KeHoachSo = kehoachso
```

it display result of

```
select *from TLU30KeHoachTuyenDung
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your parameter name is the same as the column.  That means that your `where` clause doesn't see the parameter, only the column name.

The solution is to prefix parameters.  I tend to use `p_` or `v_`:

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS tlu30khtd_findkhs //
create procedure tlu30khtd_findkhs(in p_kehoachso varchar(15)) 
begin
    select t.*
    from TLU30KeHoachTuyenDung t
    where t.KeHoachSo = p_kehoachso;
end; //
delimiter;
```